# How to create a LUT from original and processed images (not perfectly the same)?

Tags: unity, color, post-processing

I would like to create a certain LUT for my game in Unity.
The usual way would be to take a screenshot in your game, process this screenshot in an image editor like Photoshop / GIMP and then calculate the LUT from that.

I would like to re-create the LUT used in the movie [Memories of Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memories_of_Murder).

I do not have access to the un-processed film material, so I can not automatically create the LUT as I would normally do with the above approach.

The closest comparison between the original colors and the processed version that I could get were these images.

I captured them from the making of.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to create a LUT from these 2 images somehow even if they don't show exactely the same moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution in this software: "Image 2 LUT".

Here are my results, I'm really happy.

Right after loading both images, the software created a LUT for me, and it looked somewhat ok. Not perfect, but already lots better then what I tried with a manual approach in GIMP.

I played around 10 minutes with the sliders of "Image 2 LUT" without really knowing what I did, and I finally came up with something that I would consider *really close* to the original LUT.

[image]